# Pulling and printing the first object from arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to deal a card (the object) from my deck (the arraylist) and I'm having trouble trying to get the first object in the arraylist.

I've used a shuffle method (which is working and prints out the total number of cards in the newly shuffled pack) but I have no idea how to get the first object from the array (ie dealing a card from the top).

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the code you've written...?

Comment: You may want to look up `List.get()`

Comment: Could we see some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the **ArrayList.get(int index)** method. It'll return the object at the given position (index).

In your case, it'd be the **yourList.get(0)**.

Answer (score 0):

[`List#remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) will help:

```
List<String> cards = new ArrayList<>();
for (char suit : "♥♦♠♣".toCharArray())
    for (char rank : "23456789TJQKA".toCharArray())
        cards.add(String.valueOf(rank) + String.valueOf(suit));

Collections.shuffle(cards);
System.out.println(cards.remove(0)); // Q♥ //
```